# How to make a global .checked statement and call it?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Basically, I cannot make a global variable which checks if a radio button is ticked or not because it's loaded before the data is there. So I created a function. For example:

```
function a() {
  var checkRadio = document.getElementById("firstRadio").checked;
}
```

and I want to use it like this:

```
function b() {
  if (checkRadio) {

  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where and when do you call those two functions?

Comment: Yes, as you've declared your `var checkRadio`, that is *not global*.

Answer (score 1):

Move the variable declaration out of the function:

```
var checkRadio;

function a() {
    checkRadio = document.getElementById("firstRadio").checked;
}

function b() {
    if (checkRadio) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it in the parameter of the function b like this :

```
function a(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id).checked;

}

function b(a) {
  if(a) {
  }
}
```

Call b like this :

```
var checkRadio = a("firstRadio");
b(checkRadio)
```

Comment: How would you need to call `b`?

Answer (score 0):

The `checkRadio` variable only lives in the `a` function scope. Once outside (in the `b` scope for example), it doesn't exist anymore.

I would recommend not using a global variable `checkRadio` and use the `return` statement instead, like such:

```
function checkRadio(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).checked;
}

function b() {
  if (checkRadio('firstRadio')) {
    // do some stuff...
  }
}
```

Now you can use the same function (checkRadio) for any radio button that has an ID.